# this error: emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling com.something activity launch'

Tags: eclipse

Sometimes this error occurs:

> emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling ... activity launch'!

Please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to reset your adb. go to Eclipse IDE-->window--> Show Views --> device--> view menu --> reset adb

Answer (score 3):

I had also faced this problem in past and one of below solutions may solve your problem.

**first solution**

> Open Android Virtual Device Manager select the AVD you use for your
>   app. Press the start button and wait for a new form to show up called
>   (Launch Options). Check the box "Wipe user data" and hit "Launch"
>   button.

**second solution**

```
go to task manager and process
adb.exe 32* and end this process
then restart your eclipse.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it seems that AVD file was corrupted. I just created new AVD and it worked.